# How do I keep behavior and content separate when inserting HTML via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a simple to-do list app, and while it's *working*, I suspect there's something I could be doing better.

`listItem` is the class each element will have as a list item. `.delete` is a temporary solution to remove a list item.

```
$('ul').append('<li class="listItem"><h2>' + textField + '</h2><h3 class="delete">X</h3></li>')
```

Is there a way to insert this HTML while keeping the JavaScript separate from the markup? Can I save the HTML as some sort of prototype that will automatically insert the `textField` value?

I'm looking at making the markup a bit more complex for each list item, so I don't want it to get even messier. Will I need to add another framework (like AngularJS maybe) to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Is it acceptable to have this much markup in my JavaScript?

Let me know if there's any more of my code that would help to answer the question.

EDIT: It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/kfrncs/todo) if anyone's interested.

Comment: Why do you say it's a temporary solution? I mean, with the correct jQuery javascript it will be ok that way. No?

Comment: Surely the best way is AngularJS

Comment: I mean a temporary solution only because it's an "X" character being used as a button.. haha

Comment: Oh, i see ... prototyping is always temporary. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about creating a heavy javascripting rendering, perhaps there are better libraries such has Angular.js. But this question might lead to opinion based answers and be of no good. Who can tell wich framework can fit who's needs?

If your particular needs are just to implement a simple list of elements with text content and a remove button, you can use jQuery.

I [fiddled a bit of code](http://jsfiddle.net/pgJN4/) for the remove button.

```
/* element rendering [can be populated within a loop or from an array] */
var textField = "this is text";
$('ul').append('<li class="listItem"><h2>' + textField + '</h2><h3 class="deleteThis">X</h3></li>');

/* remove button */
$(document).on("click", ".deleteThis", function() {
    $(this).parent('.listItem').remove();
});
```

What you'll have to do then is just parsing your html with your text/content.

About your question : "*How do I keep behavior and content separate when inserting HTML via jQuery?*"; well, you just did it by using jQuery to `.append()` your element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, AngularJS is a pretty good practice, but you can do something similar.
For example for embedding html code in my DOM I prefer using a javascript template engine as [undercorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) (this is one of many), this is very ease and useful for repetitive html task. So your Js code will be more clean.

I recommend you to read about some javascript template engines.

Comment: I will spend the night reading that undercorejs. Thanks for the pointing.

Comment: Tomorrow, when wife and daughter come back home from vacation, i will tell them : "It's joseluisq fault".

Comment: hahaha and.. you will tell them "hey family I learned about template engines....." I suppose they will tell you, what is that? hahaha